# Создать массив дженериков

Tags: java, generics

```
public abstract class CarFactory <T extends Car> {
T[] allCars;

CarFactory(int arraySize){
    this.allCars =  new T[arraySize];
}

abstract T getCar(String model, int yearOfIssue, String color, double price, String registrationNumber);
```

}

IDE ругается на строку (на тип Т)
this.allCars =  new T[arraySize];

Подскажите, как исправить ситуацию.

Comment: с массивами так делать нельзя. и то, что вы делаете , не похоже на фабрику. решений несколько: 1)схитрить, изменив массив на коллекцию (если позволяют интерфейсы). 2)массив можно создать вызовом Array.newInstance, однако, из дженерика вы класс не получите и придется хитрить, передавая данный параметр в аргумент или что-то подобное. 3) типизировать массив суперклассом, ведь на абстрактном уровне приводить его к предку вы точно не будете. 4)делать каст к T , контролируя в методах, что именно объекты типа T  будут добавлены в массив. для конкретики нужно больше вашего кода

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое. Попробую решить через динамические массивы. Ещё раз спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю как то так

```
public abstract class CarFactory <T extends Car> {
 List<T> allCars;

 CarFactory(int arraySize){
    this.allCars =  new ArrayList<T>(arraySize);
 }

 abstract T getCar(String model, int yearOfIssue, String color, double price, String registrationNumber);
}
```

В основе ArrayList лежит array. Можете посмотреть исходники ArrayList и посмотреть реализацию данного класса. Может и найдете подсказки для вашей исходной задачи.

Comment: То есть, создать простой статический массив не получится?

Comment: Я добавил тексту. А смысл массива, хотите изобрести велосипед когда есть Generics

Comment: В любом случае это лишь способ хранения внутри класса. Программе должно быть все равно что там в нутри

Comment: Спасибо. Заменил свой код Вашим, и всё шикарно работает. Thanks.